# Mass retagger badge

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

I've been busy retaggin questions since I got my retag privileges.

Shouldn't there be an incentive to retag wrongly tagged questions, other than the urge to do things right?

I'm mean, the only "badge incentive" for retagging are "Firs edit" (Organizer) and "Creation of a tag used 50 times" (Taxonomist). The first one is easy to get, and the second one, right now in SO is almost impossible to get **without cheating**, that's editing 50 questions with an unlikely tag. Taxonomist I guess, could encourage wrongly tagging.

Is this really a problem?

We could have an "Tagged 200 question" badge, so people go for that badge, instead of taxonomist.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that tags are so light and subjective that there's really no way to indicate that it's a 'useful' retagging effort.

This badge could be easily gamed by adding "devinb" to 200 questions.
Or, if you want to look reasonable, by just retagging a bunch of C# questions with "C#-3.0" or something like that. Also by going through all the "subject" questions and adding a "language-agnostic" tag.

I don't think we want to encourage re-tagging 'just for the hell of it'. I think tagging is something that should not be incentivised, and that way we can ensure that the people who are re-tagging are people who actually want to (hopefully) improve something.

I don't think this badge will encourage good people to re-tag more. I think it will encourage the uncaring badge-mongers to re-tag more.

Comment: Originally, there was going to be a "Librarian" badge for retaggers, but it was removed for the reasons you give here.

Comment: I knew my logic sounded too good to be original.

Comment: If "easy" and "retag 200 question" don't seem contradictory to you... You have too much free time!

Answer (score 4):

Tagging is, well, editing. It's actually one of the least-expensive forms of editing too. I have spent 5 minutes reformatting code, and only a couple seconds adding tags. I don't think tagging should be exalted over editing in general.

Comment: Does it count for `Strunk & White`? If it does, then it's essentialy the same thing I'm proposing, I guess.

Comment: I know, but some of us can only retag. And spending a few afternoons retagging isn't noticed by anyone really. It's like your plumbers work. Wile everithing work well, you don't know why you need him. When something fails, you end up covered in... you get the point.

Comment: @Voyager, I believe retagging does not count towards `Strunk & White`

Comment: I though so.

Comment: It does count for the strunk & white badge

Comment: I asked this on uservoice almost a year ago, and Jeff said it did